# How to find class name from nested div in angularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

How to find the class 'myClass' from nested div in angularJS directive.  Here ng-if prevents getting css elements.Kindly help.

js:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
console.log(element[0])
}
```

html:

```
<div my-directive>
 <div class="outerDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv1"></div>
        <div class="innerDiv2"></div>
        <div class="innerDiv3">
          <p class="myClass" ng-if="">
            <p>
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can access this element using compile phase. But this question is a canonical example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/H7Q21Cw6XFRtPrxViX9j?p=preview).

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(el) {
        var className = el.find('p').attr('class')

        return function(scope, el) {
          scope.className = className
        }
    }
  }
})
```